# Plane mesh and array modifier

Tags: modifiers

I'd like to use the array modifier with a plane mesh. When relative offset is set in the two directions that are parallel to the plane, it works. But, when the relative offset is set in the orthogonal direction (z axis in the following example), it does not seem to work. Did I miss something?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Relative Offset uses the object's dimensions to generate the offset. Since the plane has no 'height' the generated copies are at the same level as the original. If you add some depth to the plane (extrude or add a Solidify modifier above the Array modifier) the Z offset will have an effect.

Use the Constant Offset (which uses absolute values) instead of Relative Offset (which uses the object dimensions) to control the array irrespective of the object's dimensions.